# bash in c/ popen cannot find my script

Tags: c, bash, popen, raspbian

I try to execute my bash script (*tes02.sh*) from a c program with `popen`. But when i run my program i get the the message: `./tes02.sh: not found`
here is the program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

#define LINE_BUFSIZE 128

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[LINE_BUFSIZE];
    int linenr;
    FILE *pipe;

    /* Get a pipe where the output from the scripts comes in */
    pipe = popen("./tes02.sh", "r");
    if (pipe == NULL) {  /* check for errors */
        perror(argv[0]); /* report error message */
        return 1;        /* return with exit code indicating error */
    }

    /* Read script output from the pipe line by line */
    linenr = 1;
    while (fgets(line, LINE_BUFSIZE, pipe) != NULL) {
        printf("Script output line %d: %s", linenr, line);
        ++linenr;
    }

    /* Once here, out of the loop, the script has ended. */
    pclose(pipe); /* Close the pipe */
    return 0;     /* return with exit code indicating success. */
}
```

The directory of my script is: `/home/pi`
should I enter the directory ? If yes, how can i do this please...
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that the current working directory of your program is what you expect (i.e. where the `tes02.sh` file is located)? Have you tried using the full absolute path?

Comment: is your script executable  and in the current working directory when executing your binary ?

Comment: @dvhh i execute the script with sudo-command "sudo ./tes02.sh"

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg the "tes02.sh" is located in "/home/pi". How i can use the full absolute path? Sorry it is the first time i use the popen

Comment: And what is the current directory when you run your C program? How *do* you run your C program?

Comment: Also, that error message doesn't look like it's coming from the `perror` call inside your program, but from the script itself. Have you properly copied and pasted the *complete* output?

Comment: The full absolute path to the script is `/home/pi/tes02.sh`. Try to use that in the `popen` call.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg my c program has another directory than my bash script. C program directory: /home/pi/programing/bashCaommand_fromC.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I tried with pipe = popen("./home/pi/tes02.sh", "r"); Same issue: ...../home/pi/tes02.sh: note found

Comment: @MorfeoRejocktana Remove the leading `.` from your full path, that makes it a *relative* path. An absolute path starts with the slash `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I would check first if the file exists in your current directory:

```
if ( 0 != access( "./tes02.sh", F_OK ) )
{ 
    fprintf ( stderr, "File tes02.sh does NOT exist in curdir\n" );
    return -1; // return code - normally I return negative codes for errors
}
/* Get a pipe where the output from the scripts comes in */
pipe = popen("./tes02.sh", "r");
if (pipe == NULL) {  /* check for errors */
    perror(argv[0]); /* report error message */
    return 1;        /* return with exit code indicating error */
}
```

(... Rest of program ...)

Answer (score 0):

You should also ensure your script begins with a shebang like `#!/bin/bash`
This allows the shell to call the interpreter.

If you can't change the script, you could try calling /bin/bash and passing the script as an argument.